# how to set background by dynamic coding

Tags: android

i used to paint the background but i want to make it drawable /picture background and the wrong in drawbackground what shall i do ?

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.download);
        float scale = (float)background.getHeight()/(float)GetHeight();
        int newWidth = Math.round(background.getWidth()/scale);
        int newHeight = Math.round(background.getHeight()/scale);
        scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);

    }
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPicture(mbgdDrawable);// draw the background
}
public void DrawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, mScreenHeight, mScreenWidth,null);
}
```

Comment: so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: he gives me error in method drawbackground

Comment: it gives you WHAT? do you want to receive any answer or not?